# Dim all children (except one being hovered on)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to hide all the children except the one being hovered on. I can't seem to figure out why it won't work - I've included the full sites CSS and everything on this

http://jsfiddle.net/DLjEg/1/

Comment: Don't forget to include the jQuery framework >_> See this fiddle, works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/DLjEg/2/

Comment: Set the library to jquery:  http://jsfiddle.net/DLjEg/3/

Comment: It works when I set the framework to jQuery - I can't find anything about a similar function in mootools on mootools.net: http://mootools.net/search/?search=1&query=hover

Comment: Do you want to hide or dim the divs.. Because it seems to be working for me.. For example if I hover on "The Great Escape" all the other divs disappear..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a jsFiddle problem. I may find the duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using jQuery, but you have the library set to MooTools...switch it to jQuery and it works fine :-)

Comment: Thank you! I feel dumb, I knew the code was good haha :)

Comment: Maybe you should click accept, then?